# Pulling data from a two-dimensional list in python

Tags: python

Hello I am trying pull information from a two-dimensional list. I read the data in using this code:

```
books = []
file_in = open(filename, 'r')

for line in file_in:
    thisline = line.split('\t')
    books.append(thisline)

file_in.close()   
return books
```

This just the code in a function. When I used to function to assign the list to book_data and then i print book_data i get this:

[['1876', 'Gore Vidal', 'Random House', '4/11/1976', 'Fiction\n'], ['23337', 'Stephen King', 'Scribner', '11/27/2011', 'Fiction\n'], ['...and Ladies of the Club', 'Helen Hooven Santmeyer', 'Putnam', '7/8/1984', 'Fiction\n'], ['1st to Die', 'James Patterson', 'Little, Brown', '3/25/2001', 'Fiction\n']]

But when i try to do something like:

```
for book in books:
       print(book)
```

All i get in return in the first book:['1876', 'Gore Vidal', 'Random House', '4/11/1976', 'Fiction\n']

I need to be able to go through each book and compare items in those books but I cant even seem to get the whole list to print using a loop. I actually need to be able to search through it by the authors name.

Comment: there's no `book_data` in your initial code. Update your question

Comment: Right before that loop, what does `print(len(books))` show?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the

```
l = [element_1, element_2, ..., element_n]
for element in l:
    print(element)
```

syntax, as expected that's going to print all elements one by one, and if each element is a list, then it's going to print each one of those lists one by one.

If you do

```
books = [['1876', 'Gore Vidal', 'Random House', '4/11/1976', 'Fiction\n'], ['23337', 'Stephen King', 'Scribner', '11/27/2011', 'Fiction\n'], ['...and Ladies of the Club', 'Helen Hooven Santmeyer', 'Putnam', '7/8/1984', 'Fiction\n'], ['1st to Die', 'James Patterson', 'Little, Brown', '3/25/2001', 'Fiction\n']]
```

And then run the for-loop you have there, it *is* going to print each list that represents a book one by one. Maybe it's a problem with what's actually inside books or book_data once you get there (whichever one you are trying to print from)

Separately, consider using dictionaries to represent each book, that way you can be more explicit and structured about its properties (rather than just rely on remembering which index number corresponds to which book property) and do things like

```
if some_book['author'] == "Dude McAuthorson":
    do_something()
```